# Data Migration Parse to Firebase. Directions

Tags: parse-platform, firebase

My app currently uses Parse and it's time to migrate. I am either considering hosting my own Parse Server or use Firebase. I am looking for guidance on how to approach my data migration problem to Firebase based on my current data model.

I have a table Users and that table, aside from all the normal columns, has `Partner` column which is of type `User`.

The flow, works like this:

1. User 1 signs up
2. User 1 invites User 2
3. User 2 receives invite e-mail with invite code
4. User 2 goes to app and signs-up using that code
5. And then I have a Parse cloud function that joins both users as partners adding each other's IDs to the respective column.

The partners are connected via a GCM topic name, so I can push notifications just to these two people.

So this is what I would like to achieve in Firebase. I would like to have two users to connect together in a way.

Maybe I could have a json like this:

```
partners: {
    topic_name_partner1: {
        user1: {info about user1},
        user2: {info about user2}
    },
    topic_name_partner2: {
        user1: {info about user1},
        user2: {info about user2}
    },
    topic_name_partner3: {
        user1: {info about user1},
        user2: {info about user2}
    }
    ....etc
}
```

Would this approach make sense ? Obviously I want a scalable application, so looking for help as well to best represent the data in that sense.

And, lastly, does Firebase have Cloud Functions like Parse? If not, how can I connect both users when the second user is registering? Maybe I have to look up Ref for the `topic_name_partner1` string and then when finding it, update user2 with the reference to that user?

Thanks!

Comment: In your Parse setup, you are sending the invite via email. Would there be an option to have that invite sent in the app itself? I'm asking as Firebase has very limited email features (almost none) so to continue that functionality, you'll need to integrate another company that does emails.

Comment: I am actually generating my invite code and sending emails out using a private server I have (PHP). Doesn't Firebase have the Invites package? I thought it was meant to be awesome

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this firebase structure guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures), here is what I will do

```
users: {
    user1: {
        name: "user1",
        partner: "topic_name_partner1",
        ... other info
    },
    user2: {
        name: "user2",
        partner: "topic_name_partner1",
        ... other info
    },
    user3: {
        name: "user3",
        partner: "topic_name_partner2",
        ... other info
    }
}
partners: {
    topic_name_partner1: {
        user1: true,
        user2: true
    },
    topic_name_partner2: {
        user3: true
    }
}
```

so the data will not so big when I just want to get a list of users in a partner without their details.

and currently Firebase does not have Cloud Functions feature like Parse, so you have to move the data from the client (or probably use their Firebase SDK for server).

Comment: Thanks Wilik, that sure helps. I will do some tests and see how I get on with your suggestion!